# Save and load a singleton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, singleton

I have created a singleton like this:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedDataStore {

static SSDataStore *_sharedDataStore = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _sharedDataStore = [[self alloc] init];
});

return _sharedDataStore;
}
```

What is the best way of saving and loading it to and from the documents folder?
I tried saving it with NSKeyedArchiver, but I don't know how to load it afterwards. What do I do instead of

```
 _sharedDataStore = [[self alloc] init];
```

?

Comment: Save what, its values? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried saving it with NSKeyedArchiver, but I don't know how to load it afterwards. What do I do instead of

       _sharedDataStore = [[self alloc] init];
?

Comment: Why do you want to save singleton object. You should store your properties on disc and a sinleton shoud make sure that you access right file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restore the state of your singleton, you need to implement the `initWithCoder` method from the `NSCoding` protocol. Something like:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.property1 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"property1"];
    self.property2 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"property2"];

    return self;
}
```

- See [NSCoding/NSKeyedArchiver](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) on NSHipster for more details.

Comment: I did that, but how do I check if the object already exists on the disk or if I have to initialise it?

Comment: @sixbeat You don't need to worry about the object on the disk, the archiving system will do that for you.